# Bootstrap Freeze thead on table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to freeze my first row in my html table (thead) but when I try the following CSS code:

```
table {
    width: 100% !important;
}

thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}

tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

thead th {
    height: 30px;
}

tbody {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The thead is not the same size as the tbody. the tbody is scrollable to the thead is in a fixed position, but not the same, the tr's are bunched up together. Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="MVCGridTable_Grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bxeyo8tv/1/) I tried to put together, but the **Bootstrap** I added appears not to be working so excuse the lack of styling:

This is the result I get:

[image]

Comment: `I am trying to freeze my first row in my html table`. You want to freeze the thead with respect to the table or the screen?

Comment: @Sunil example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0xu5d1tk/ when thead is fixed wrt table

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h1jrpo3v/ when thead is fixed wrt screen

Comment: try scrolling the page in both the fiddles. I think one of these might solve your issue as well

Comment: I tried both solutions, both gave the same result as I did before...I attached a screenshot

Comment: @user979331 what do you mean by `freeze the first row`???

Answer (score 9):

For this to work you need to wrap your table in an element with `position: relative`, a `height` or `max-height` (note some versions of IE have/had some trouble with `calc()` in `max-height`) translatable by browser into a physical size and to apply to each and every `th/td` inside your sticky `<thead>` the class of `sticky-top` or, if you prefer, the following CSS:

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
z-index: 1020;
```

See it working:

```js
"use strict";

var stickySituation = function stickySituation(o) {
  return $("".concat(o, " .sticky-top")).css('position') === 'fixed';
};

var updateStickyHeader = function updateStickyHeader(i, e) {
  var cell = $("tbody tr>*:nth-child(".concat(i + 1, ")"), $(e).closest('table')).eq(0)[0];

  if (cell) {
    var box = cell.getBoundingClientRect();
    $(e).css({
      top: 0,
      width: box.width,
      height: box.height,
      left: box.left
    });
  }
};

$(window).on('load', function () {
  var sh = '.table-responsive.sticky-headers';
  $('thead th').addClass('sticky-top bg-white');

  if (stickySituation(sh)) {
    $(sh).css({
      paddingTop: $('tbody tr>*:nth-child(1)', sh).eq(0).css('height')
    });
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
      $('thead th').each(updateStickyHeader);
    });
    $(window).trigger('resize');
  }
});
```

```css
.table-responsive {
  max-height: 100vh;
  /* whatever makes sense */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.table-responsive .sticky-top {
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 gainsboro;
  /* hack for IE: */ position: fixed;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive position-relative sticky-headers">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">5</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">6</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">7</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">8</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">9</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Updated:** Added JS for browsers without support for `position: sticky` (i.e: IE).
Modern day browsers only need line `23` from script (which only adds the `sticky-top` and `bg-white` classes to each `<th>`, which could obviously be done manually).
That is to say **you don't actually need the JS part in modern browsers for this to work** (as long as you apply the classes (or the CSS rules) to your markup, as stated above).

Comment: This kinda works....it adds an extra scroll bar and there is a little space at the top where you can see the table scroll

Comment: You never mentioned it has to work in IE. Nobody uses IE anymore, except for website owners and developers checking if their websites are working in it. It has a combined market share of ~2% across all versions, surpassed by UC Browser, Samsung Internet and Opera. If you're targeting IE, why are you using Bootstrap? Read the disclaimer in their [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/#internet-explorer). One of the unsupported features they refer to is `position: sticky`.

Comment: I added a hack to make it work in IE. As for the *"from a reputable source"* part, can't help you there, mate. If I knew that's what you're looking for when I answered your question, I wouldn't have bothered. I'm utterly disreputable.

Comment: To get read of the second scrollbar, remove ***all*** your CSS attempts to achieve a sticky header on this table. Namely, you have to remove the set `height` on `tbody` and the `overflow-y: auto` from your CSS. Instead, place the desired height on `.table-responsive`, instead of the `100vh` i used. This is about as much as I can help you without a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

try to implement this way.

```js
$(".table_container").scroll(function(){
  var topPosition = $(".table_container").scrollTop();
  $("#MVCGridTable_Grid thead tr th").css({"top": (topPosition)});
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.table_container {
  max-height: 180px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
thead tr th{
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="table_container">
  <table id="MVCGridTable_Grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>aaa</th>
     <th>aaa</th>
     <th>aaa</th>
     <th>aaa</th>
     <th>aaa</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
     <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this solution is works for you.

**I checked it for IE also, its shaking while scroll but works fine this is because of browser response in other browser it works smoothly.**

Thank you...

Comment: I just set table header position: relative and update it's top position using simple jquery nothing else.

Comment: Does it works for you or not please add comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Having same request from client in current project. I just create sweet and simple code snippet. Try this i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
table thead th {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0.125rem 0 0.1875rem #dee2e6;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table id="MVCGridTable_Grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just Modified your code, it is one of the possible solution you can
>   try

```
    table{
       border-collapse: collapse;
}
table thead{
    padding-right: 17px; // scroll width is 17px wide
}
thead th, td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to given particular width to table cells to achieve proper alignment with table body scroll.

```css
table {
    width: 100% !important;
    border: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}

tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

thead th {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

tbody {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

tr th, tr td {
  width: 200px;
  text-align:center;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table id="MVCGridTable_Grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
            <th>aaa</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can check the scroll behaviour by running above code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

add sticky class to your

```
.sticky{
 position:absolute
}
```

and max-height to your tbody