# Scrollable (horizontally and vertically) HTML table with fixed header and specific number of columns (compatible with IE 11)

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, fixed

I have HTML table for which I need fixed header, fixed specific number of columns, vertical and horizontal scrolling and compatibility with IE 11.

I've tried this plugin https://yidas.github.io/jquery-freeze-table/ but it is extremely slow in IE 11.

Possible solution could be with fixed columns and using repeating header after each 15 rows
with horizontal and vertical scrolling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Freeze thead on table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254931/bootstrap-freeze-thead-on-table)

Comment: Here is screenshot:
https://i.ibb.co/X5qbPpx/fixed-columns-header.png
I need fix columns "checkbox", A, B, C, S, I and table header.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using pure css:

Here is the fiddle:

```css
.table {
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

tbody th {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  left: 0;
}

thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

thead th:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

thead th {
  background: yellow;
  color: #FFF;
}

tbody th {
  background: red;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>col6</th>
        <th>col7</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>dfgdf</th>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>dfgdf</th>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>dfgdf</th>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>dfdf</th>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>dfgdf</th>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>fgdf</th>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be great if I had only one row header and one fixed column.

Comment: @Rado not getting your poing one row header means?

Comment: Here is screenshot: i.ibb.co/X5qbPpx/fixed-columns-header.png I need fix columns "checkbox", A, B, C, S, I and table header.